# Which directory should I install on my 32GB SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have a Dell Inspiron 14z with 32GB of SSD and 500GB on regular HDD.
Since I would not be able to install the full system on the SSD, which directory or directories should I install on the SSD and which ones should I leave to the regular HDD in order to have the best performance possible?

Comment: *"Since I would not be able to install the full system on the SSD"* You probably would, actually.

Comment: 32 GB is in almost all caes enoigh for all system related stuff and installs, i would put the `/home`onto the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Videonauth's](https://askubuntu.com/users/522934/videonauth) comment - I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed on a 30GB partition of my Ultrabook's SSD, and I still have space for a few files.

Install to the SSD, and put your `/home` on the HDD.